# ajax does not receive response from nodejs

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

Got a registration form with ajax script, POSTing to nodejs backend.
The problem is that ajax request is hanging for up to 30-60 seconds before executing "error" or (sometimes!) "success" events. If timeout is set, error is fired after 3 secs. Node backend writes the results to console immediately. Is something wrong with ajax or backend?

**HTML:**

```
    <form id="add" action="" class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="input">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="input">pass</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="new" value="new" id="new">
            <input type="hidden" name="role" value="admin" id="role">
        </div>
        <div id="submit" class="btn">Add</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function () {


        $('#submit').on('click', function() {

            var form = $('#add');
            var data = {"username":$('#username').val(), "password": $('#pass').val() , "role": $('#role').val(), "new": $('#new').val()}

            alert ('ajax start: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            $.ajax({
                url: '/add',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
    //            timeout : 3000,

                success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr) {
                    console.log("Worked!" + responseText);
                    alert ('success');

                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert ('complete');

                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log('err:');
                    console.log(err);
                    alert ('err: ' + err.statusCode() + " " + err.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**route to process the request:**

```
    module.exports = function(req, res) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty("new")){
            //add new user
            console.log('new');
            var Auth = app.locals.Auth;
            Auth.register(req, function (err){
                console.log('ended registration');
                if (err){
                    console.log('err: ' + err + res);

                    res.json({"err":err});
                }else{
                    console.log('successfully registered');
                    res.json({"success":'success'});
                }
                console.log('res.end');
                res.end();
                console.log('return');
                return ;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in route code:

```
    res.end();
```

just needed to remove this row

Answer (score 0):

It seems the okay code to me. Actually only change I could suggest you is to add an error code as well as success code to your response.

Success: `res.json(200, {"success": "success"});`

Error: `res.json(400, {"error": err});`

Comment: Jay Sri Ram. Still very long wait time.

Comment: Are you getting the response?

Comment: js Console immediately logs "400 - bad request", but "complete" is triggered much later

Comment: i receive the response, but ajax seems ro be waiting for something else, triggers are executed at page reload, after backend restart or after a very long timeout.

Comment: When I send this request from [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm/related), it fails to receive any response

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. I added this to my code : `res.json(400, {"error": err});` so it is normal, it tells me , that this user is registered. The problem is, that ajax does not trigger "error" or "complete" event.

Comment: @Schtz: A ok sorry then.